# How to create Regex to filter out results with few complex conditions regarding length, case and classes of characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following filtered:

- 2 digits `(?=..*\d)`
- 2 uppercase characters `(?=..*[a-z])`
- 2 lowercase characters `(?=..*[A-Z])`
- 10 to 63 characters `.{10,63}$`

Which translates to:

```
(?=.{2,}\d)(?=..*[a-z])(?=..*[A-Z]).{10,63}
```

Then I want to exclude a word starting with the letter u, and ending with three to six digits:

```
([uU][0-9]{3,6})
```

However, how can I merge these two patterns to do the following:

**It should not allow the following because it respectively:**

```
# does not have the required combination of characters
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

# is too long
asadsfdfs12BDFsdfsdfdsfsdfsdfdsfdsfdfsdfsdfsdfsdsfdfsdfsdfssdfdfsdfssdfdfsdfssdfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsfdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs

# contains the pattern that shouldn't be allowed
U0000ABcd567890
ABcd56U00007890
D4gF3U432234
D4gF3u432234
ABcd567890U123456
```

**should allow the following:**

```
# it has the required combination of characters
ABcd5678990
ABcd567890

# does contain a part of the disallowed pattern (`([uU][0-9]{3,6})`), but does not fit that pattern entirely
ABcd567890U12
ABcd5U12abcdf
s3dU00sDdfgdg
ABcd56U007890
```

Created and example here: https://regex101.com/r/4b2Hu9/3

Comment: my advice would be to split this into multiple regexes - test every condition separately.

Comment: I can't understand the pattern or why the entries should be allowed. Could you detail a bit more, please?

Comment: Your assertions are not correct. For example `(?=.{2,}\d)` does not mean 2 digits, it means if what is directly on the right is 2 or more times any char except a newline followed by a single digit. The same goes for uppercase and lowercase (which is reversed in the question). Why is `ABcd567890` allowed as it ends with 6 digits?

Comment: @ControlAltDel Good point. I could seperate them into smaller chuncks as a named function which would make it more readable. Still interested in how to merge it into one though.

Comment: @gustavovelascoh added more detail, does it provide more meaning?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Ah, good point regarding the 2 digits. Will have to check it for the correct regex. And: Your example is allowed since the six digits aren't proceeded with a 'u' or 'U'

Comment: Do you mean matching 2 consecutive digits and a-z or do you mean that the string must at least contain 2 digits, 2 times a-z and 2 times A-Z?

Comment: Why does the last one `ABcd56U007890` match? it ends on `U` and 6 digits? See https://regex101.com/r/DF4UHp/1

Comment: Nice find, you're right. It should not match. The digits do not have to be consecutive, it should just be present. You're example is exactly what I mean!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pattern you make use of a lookahead `(?=..*\d)` which has a different meaning than you assume.

It means if what is directly on the right is 2 or more times any char except a newline followed by a single digit and the same for the upper and lowercase variants.

You could update your pattern to:

```
^(?!.*[uU]\d{3,6})(?=(?:\D*\d){2})(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2})(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2}).{10,63}$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!.*[uU]\d{3,6})` Negative lookahead, assert not `u` or `U` followed by 3-6 digits
- `(?=(?:\D*\d){2})` Assert 2 digits
- `(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2})` Assert 2 lowercase chars
- `(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2})` Assert 2 uppercase chars
- `.{10,63}` Match any char except a newline 10-63 times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DF4UHp/1)

Comment: ++ Good one, this should work. You can replace `[^\d]` with `\D`

Answer (score 0):

First, the way to ensure that the string contains, for example, two digits would be to use a positive lookahead:

```
(?=.*\d.*\d)
```

You can generalize this to your other filters.

To make sure the string contains 10 - 63 characters:

```
.{10,63}
```

You say you do not want the string to begin with u or U followed by 3 to 6 digits (presumbaly 7 digits is okay), use a negative lookahead:

```
(?![uU]\d{3,6}\D)
```

The `\D` is required to make sure that if there is a 7th digit, then the string will be accepted.

Putting it all together:

```
r'^(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?![uU]\d{3,6}\D).{10,63}$'
```